# Why no solution is showing in C-PLEX with no error in code?

Tags: php, error-handling, constraints, cplex, conflict

The conflict is showing after initializing constraints. Conflict is in ct2.Following is the code.I compiled the code without any error. Conflict is showing 35 onwards. I have marked that line in my code

> minimize 0.5*sum(i in tavail)((pt[i]-pl[i])+sum(j in number)pevch[i][j]*c[i]+sum(j in number)-pevdis[i][j]*c[i]);
> subject to
> {35:ct1:forall(i in tavail)
> {if(pl[i]<7000000)
> c[i]==2.5;
> ct2:if(7000000<=pl[i]<=10000000)
> c[i]==3.5;
> ct3:if(pl[i]>10000000)
> c[i]==5;}
> ct4:forall(i in tavail,j in number)
> {ct5:if(pt[i]-pl[i]<0 && 0.7<soc[j][i]<0.9&&c[i]==3.5&&c[i]==5)
> {pevdis[i][j]==(0.9-soc[j][i])*100000;
>
> }
> else
> pevdis[i][j]==0;}
>
> forall(i in tavail,j in number)
> ct6:{if(pt[i]-pl[i]>0 && soc[j][i]<=0.7&&c[i]==3.5&&c[i]==2.5 )
> {pevch[i][j]==(0.7-soc[j][i])*100000;
>
> }
> else
> pevch[i][j]==0;}}
> forall(i in tavail,j in number)
> ct7:{pl[i]==pl[i]+pevch[i][j]-pevdis[i][j];}
>
> }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your model is not feasible so you get some conflicts and relaxations.

If you want to see that in scripting, see technote

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/display-conflict-and-relaxation-information-infeasible-models-using-opl-script

Comment: I just added the code you have provided, starting from main.However, it demonstrates that the solution failed. C-PLEX status=3